# FabPro 1000 making flat little discs?

Tags: troubleshooting, resin

I'm just getting into 3D printing, and I got a FabPro 1000 (to make miniatures, mainly). I've tested it by trying to print a few things, but it's been a disaster every time: [image: my 3D printing attempts]

It just prints out these flat little discs that have fallen into the resin-filled tray, not stuck to the top surface as they should. I don't have an agitator, but I shake the material really well before use and fill the tray a decent amount. [Here](https://mega.nz/#!1ZcWnSJT!WHHhKz3LgXE4piKEYA1wgYr9UMWMjloZD6SIX88pWhE)'s my latest config file, if anyone wants to see.

Is my printer broken or am I doing something wrong? How can I figure out what's causing this to happen? Is there any other information I should provide?

Comment: Did you level the bed? A slight Angle is enough to prevent good printing. How old is your resin and what's the brand as well as the expiration date? The stuff can go bad and some brands do need longer exposure times than others.